# How can I constantly update an image?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a website that allows me to see my screen.
But I don't know how I can get the image it's displaying to constantly change.
Thanks for the help

Here is my current JS code:

```
window.onload = refreshBlock();
function refreshBlock()
{
    document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' width='1000' height='500'></img>"
    setInterval("refreshBlock();",100);
}
```

Comment: Put the `setInterval` outside the function.

Comment: what do you mean with *"constantly update an image"*? Like a Video(-stream)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are two different built-in JavaScript functions to execute some code with a delay.

1. `setInterval()` will execute the code every X milliseconds automatically, while
2. `setTimeout()` will execute the code once after X milliseconds

What you're currently doing is calling `refreshBlock()` every 100 milliseconds, and in that function generating a new interval, so after a few iterations, you end up with hundreds of intervals growing exponentially.

You can either put `setInterval()` outside of the callback function or call `setTimeout` inside of the callback function to avoid this.

In addition to that,

```
window.onload = refreshBlock();
```

is not doing what you think it's doing. By calling the function via `()`, you are setting `window.onload` to the result of the execution of `refreshBlock()`. By that time, any elements referenced inside the function might not yet be in the DOM. Instead, you want to set merely the function reference as the onload callback on the window object:

```
window.onload = refreshBlock;
```

Comment: The other thing of course is that they need a list of image files to rotate, or some other means of obtaining a new image...right now it just displays the same one every time

Comment: Good catch, I missed that. If caching is either disabled browser-wide or server-side via expires headers or other means of preventing caching, it should already work. Otherwise, adding some form of cache busting like a query with a timestamp should do the trick.

Comment: Regardless of caching though it will load the exact same image every time, so the current code will do nothing useful. There's nothing to vary the URL which is loaded

Comment: I assumed the image file would be constantly updated on the server

Comment: I suppose that could be the case... unusual though, unless the URL pointed to a server side script to randomly pull a new image from a data store or something. The example just points to a jpg. But I agree the question doesn't really day exactly what the desired outcome should be

Comment: @Connum yes the image file is being constantly changed I should have specified, sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to only change the SRC of the image instead of the whole tag:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="video">
<img src='image1.jpg' width='1000' height='500' id="image"></img>
</div>
<script>
window.onload = refreshBlock;
function refreshBlock()
{
    document.getElementById("image").src="image4.jpg";
    setTimeout("refreshBlock",1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also "setTimeout" is more what you need than "setInterval".

Comment: Should be `setTimeout("refreshBlock",1000);` - without the brackets. The settimeout should receive a reference to the function to be executed, not the result of already executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `window.onload` event to start your updates.  The code below start as soon as the page is loaded, loops every `100ms` and terminates when you close or reload the page.

```
let handle = setInterval( () => {
    document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' width='1000' height='500'></img>" 
}, 100);
```

To terminate the `setInterval` loop at any time you can use `clearInterval(handle)`

Answer (score 0):

you want o change the images constantly  this is a simple example for three images it will keep switching between these images constantly so by another meaning the images will keep changing there are many example i have but i believe this is the easiest one

```
refreshBlock();
function refreshBlock() {
  var x = 0;
//image 1
  document.getElementById("v").innerHTML =" <img src='image1.jpg' width='1000' height='500'></img>";
  setInterval(function() {
    if (x == 0) {
        //image 2
      document.getElementById("v").innerHTML =" <img src='image2.jpg' width='1000' height='500'></img>";
    } else if (x == 1) {
        //image 3
      document.getElementById("v").innerHTML =" <img src='image3.jpg' width='1000' height='500'></img>";
    }
    x++;

    if (x == 2) {
      x = 0;
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```